# Using Play/Anorm with more than 22 fields?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, anorm

I'm using the "computer-database" sample app as a guide on how to create models using Anorm. The problem I've run into is the "22 parameter" limitation. Is there a workaround, or a sample app that deals with this?

Please assume that having >22 fields in this case is not a "sign of bad design", but a domain-specific requirement.

Comment: It's somewhat related (Play is Scala based), but this is about a specific Anorm implementation.

Comment: The "workaround" is normalizing your data.

Comment: Like I said, please assume that data is already normalized.